# IIS vs. Standalone ASP.NET app with Kestrel

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET app running Kestrel.

I used to deploy it under IIS and everything worked fine.. until yesterday!

I have no idea what has changed, but the app now starts, stops and restarts and stops in an endless loop. There is no error message, no crash, absolutely nothing indicates what the problem is.

If I run the app standalone and use IIS as a reverse proxy, it works perfectly.

Is there a way to log what is happening under IIS?  The server logs don't mention anything at all.

Comment: What version of .NET framework are you using? have you recently changed the target framework? have you made any changes in the IIS virtual app configuration?

Comment: I'm using 4.6; I just renamed the target folder as the project is merged into another one and the name is changing, but that's pretty much it. I'm leaning toward a permission issue that somehow doesn't get reported

Comment: ASP.NET Core apps should only be run standalone and use IIS as reverse proxy. I am not sure what you mean by "deploy it under IIS".

Comment: Right now we have all the apps in folders seen by IIS as a website and IIS is managing their lifecycle; we're moving the whole thing to docker pretty soon and will use IIS as a reverse proxy only